# "shoals of immigrants" Is this a correct usage of a metaphor?

Tags: phrase-usage, metaphors, figurative-language

> Although the onset of the problems of climate change may seem
> minuscule and peculiar to some poor regions in the world, the
> long-term repercussions of such a trend will be evident in a
> not-too-distant future when giant **shoals of immigrants** from destitute countries flood prosperous countries.

In the above sentence, I wanted to say that immigrants will migrate to prosperous countries to evade the problems resulted from climate change in their own native countries. But I am trying to emphasize that this migration will be out of control and cannot be managed. So I used the word shoal to mean that this something that just happens and nobody leads it.

1. Is is grammatically correct to say shoals of people? because I saw in dictionaries that shoal is used for fish. Is it metaphoric to say "shoals of people", Is it correct grammatically?
2. I hope it is not rude to say that immigrants move in shoals, is it?

Comment: Obviously it's "rude". But the usage has very little currency anyway. Certainly not by comparison with [***hordes** of immigrants*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hordes+of+immigrants%2Cshoals+of+immigrants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chordes%20of%20immigrants%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshoals%20of%20immigrants%3B%2Cc0) (also inherently derogatory).

Comment: It's perfectly grammatically correct, but *shoals* is a rather rare word, and not often used metaphorically, so it reads strangely.

Comment: Seems to be a component of *ad* *baculum*  https://philosophy.lander.edu/logic/force.html

Comment: Do immigrants move in shoals? Shoals implies some form of coordination, synchronisation, or [flocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flocking_(behavior)). In contrast refugees usually move singly or in small groups, unconnected from other refugees (the exception would be the so-called refugee caravans which allegedly menace Central America).

Comment: No, it just doesn't make sense semantically. shoals means a bunch of fish OR submerged rocks in the ocean. You can try: throngs or large groups or plethoras or hordes (as Fumble Fingers said) I'm sorry but "giant shoals of immigrants" is LOL. It just is.

Comment: Gosh, this question has come around again.

Answer (score 1):

There's a larger problem here: by using the verb "flood," you have a [mixed metaphor](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-mixed-metaphor-1691395). Fish do not flood. The two words are related, of course, both involving water. If you want to keep the verb "flood" you might want to change the noun to "wave" (or even "*tsunami*," for your desired connotation of "out-of-control and unmanageable"), "surge" (e.g. a "storm surge"), or similar.

But if you want to avoid "rudeness," it might be wise to avoid metaphors altogether. People are conscious, decision-making beings, and any metaphor that likens them to animals, forces of nature, or inanimate objects runs a risk of being conceptually degrading (at worst, in so subtle a way that the author and reader can remain unaware of it). A more human rewrite might be:

> ... in a not-too-distant future when refugees from countries devastated by climate change appeal to countries less affected.

Answer (score 0):

Cambridge dictionary (predominantly British English) defines "shoal" as "*a large number of fish swimming as a group*".

However, Webster's dictionary (predominantly American English) defines "shoal" as simply "*a large group or number*", although it does use "shoals of fish" as an example.

In answer to your first question then, there is at least an argument that the term could be used beyond fish, but there is no escaping the fact that it is primarily associated with them.

While the second part of your question might be opinion-based, I would have to say that it could be offensive if used to describe immigrants. Many persons described as "immigrants" in a country are there perfectly legally, but likening them to fish might suggest that they 'swam' over to a country illegally.

To be honest, the overall tone of your sentence does come over as negative towards immigrants anyway. Unless your wider context is more kind of them, it seems to frame immigrants as a problem. If not being rude about them is important to you, you might want to consider focusing more on the migration you speak about being a consequence rather than a threat.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for "journalistically correct" language:

when **very large numbers** of immigrants from destitute countries **flock** to prosperous countries.

when **plethoras** of immigrants from destitute countries flee to or seek refuge prosperous countries.

A few idea....

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with it grammatically, but it uses an unusual word in an iffy metaphor. You've already pointed to the magnitude of the problem with the strong word *flood*, so there's no reason to find a grouping term for immigrants -
You could just say

> ... when immigrants flood prosperous countries.

If you still want to underline the size of the problem,

> ... when immigrants in huge numbers flood prosperous countries.